# Ansible: Find /path/*/filename and change several lines

Tags: ansible

This is my directory tree:

```
.
├── unknown_dir1
│   └── firefox.conf
└── unknown_dir2
    └── firefox.conf
```

I need to find every instance of file `firefox.conf` and change some of their parameters. 
My task is the following:

```
- name: configure firefox
   lineinfile:
     dest= [?]
     state=present
     regexp=.*{{ item.value }}.*
     line='user_pref("{{ item.value }}", {{ item.key }});'
     insertafter=EOF
     backup=yes
   with_tems:
     - { value: 'browser.startup.page', key: '0' }
     - { value: 'network.cookie.cookieBehavior', key: '3' }
```

*The problem* is that firefox.conf files are found under *unknown directories*.

**How** could I search for each file instance and specify it in the `dest` entry of `lineinfile` module?

I tried to register the output of a `find` command before the prepended task:

```
- name: find firefox.confs
  shell: find /vagrant/* -type f -name "firefox.conf"
  register: files_to_change
```

However I cannot find out how to tackle with both list and dictionaries in the `with_items`/`with_nested`/`with_subelements`/`you_name_it` section of the `configure firefox` task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
- name: configure firefox
   lineinfile:
     dest={{ item[0] }}
     state=present
     regexp=.*{{ item[1].value }}.*
     line='user_pref("{{ item[1].value }}", {{ item[1].key }});'
     insertafter=EOF
     backup=yes
   with_nested:
    - files_to_change.stdout_lines
    -
     - { value: 'browser.startup.page', key: '0' }
     - { value: 'network.cookie.cookieBehavior', key: '3' }
```

Explanation:

[with_nested](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops) will apply the lineinfile replacements on every file found by the output of the previous task.

Comment: Indeed. The key is that all firefox values are entered as sub-entries of the second entry. Thank you!